# JavaScript createElement

Tags: javascript

I downloaded a livesearch javascript plugin for my site, it's working, but I need help to modify it a little bit.

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({url: $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search/ajax&keyword=' + keywords, dataType: 'json', type: 'GET', success: function(result) {
    if( result.length > 0 ) {
        var eList = document.createElement( 'ul' );
        eList.id = 'livesearch_search_results';
        var eListElem;
        var eLink;
        var eHref;
        for( var i in result ) {
            eListElem = document.createElement( 'li' );
            eLink = document.createElement( 'a' );
            if( result[i].img != null ) {
                eImg = new Image();
                eImg.src = result[i].img;
            }
            else {
                eImg = document.createElement( 'span' );
                eImg.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
            }
            eDiv = document.createElement( 'div' );
            eLink.appendChild( document.createTextNode(result[i].name) );
            if( typeof(result[i].href) != 'undefined' ) {
                eHref = result[i].href;
            }
            else {
                eHref = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/product&product_id=' + result[i].product_id + '&keyword=' + keywords;
            }
            eLink.href = eHref;
            eDiv.appendChild( eLink );
            eDiv.innerHTML = eDiv.innerHTML + result[i].desc;
            eListElem.appendChild( eImg );
            eListElem.appendChild( eDiv );
            eListElem.appendChild( document.createElement('br') );
            eListElem.setAttribute( 'rel', eHref );
            $(eListElem).bind('click', function(){
                var gto = $(this).attr( 'rel' );
                try {
                    if( gto != false && gto.length > 0 ) {
                        document.location = gto;
                    }
                }
                catch( e ) {}
            });
            eList.appendChild( eListElem );
        }
        if( $('#livesearch_search_results').length > 0 ) {
            $('#livesearch_search_results').remove();
        }
        $('#search_menu').append(eList);
    }
}});
```

The output is something like this:

```
<li rel="http://url"><img src="http://url.jpg">
<div><a href="url">TITLE</a>Description</div>
<br></li>
```

Is there any way to add a  element to the  tag? Like this:

```
<li rel="http://url"> <span class="img_container"><img src="http://url.jpg"> </span>
<div><a href="url">TITLE</a>Description</div>
<br></li>
```

I know, that I can create a  tag with `document.createElement( 'span' )`, but I don't know where is exactly going in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the lines

```
eImg = new Image();
eImg.src = result[i].img;
```

with

```
var eImg = document.createElement( 'span' );
eImg.className = "img_container";
var img = new Image();
img.src = result[i].img;
eImg.appendChild( img );
```

Btw, the script author forget to declare the variable `eImg` as local. I doubt this was on purpose.